# How to get SQL data inside a Javascipt if function

Tags: javascript, sql, function, variables, get

I have these two columns in my table: `effective_start_datetime` and `effective_end_datetime`

[image: 1]

In my function I am trying to do an if condition for three situations:
`Inactive` if `effective_start_datetime` is null, `Active` if `effective_end_datetime` is null, else show a custom date without the time (e.g. `From: 2021-08-23 To: 2021-08-25`)

**UI:**

[image: 2]

Code Snippet: (I used `shift.` to get the column data from the table)

```
<td>${getshiftstatus(shift.effective_start_datetime, shift.effective_end_datetime)}</td>

                    function getshiftstatus(start_datetime, end_datetime) {
                        var s_status = '';
                        if (start_datetime === null) {
                            s_status = '<p class="text-danger">Inactive</p>';
                        } else if (end_datetime === null) {
                            s_status = '<p class="text-success">Active</p>';
                        }  else {
                            s_status = '<p>Custom</p>';
                        }
                        return s_status;  }
```

I am trying to change `s_status = '<p>Custom</p>';` into a custom date like:

```
s_status = '<table><tr class="row-gray"><td class="p-0 font-weight-bold">From:</td><td class="tb-schedule">2021-08-23</td></tr><tr class="row-gray"><td class="p-0 font-weight-bold">To:</td><td class="tb-schedule">2021-08-25</td></tr></table>';
```

The code above gives me:

[image: 3]

But when I tried to add the variables I am getting a string instead of the SQL data:

```
s_status = '<table><tr class="row-gray"><td class="p-0 font-weight-bold">From:</td><td class="tb-schedule">${shift.effective_start_datetime}</td></tr><tr class="row-gray"><td class="p-0 font-weight-bold">To:</td><td class="tb-schedule">${shift.effective_end_datetime}</td></tr></table>';
```

[image: 4]

How do I get my SQL `shift.` data in my function variable?

UPDATE:

I am getting `shift is not defined` after using a backtick. It seems like my `shift.` is not getting read inside my function

```
 s_status = `<table><tr class="row-gray"><td class="p-0 font-weight-bold">From:</td><td class="tb-schedule">${shift.effective_start_datetime}</td></tr><tr class="row-gray"><td class="p-0 font-weight-bold">To:</td><td class="tb-schedule">${shift.effective_end_datetime}</td></tr></table>`;
```

[image: 5]

Comment: Use backticks (ie `\``) instead if single-quotes (ie `'`) around your `s_status` string

Comment: I am getting shift is not defined after using the backtick

Comment: That's simply a scoping problem. You would need to pass your `shift` object into the `getshiftstatus` function